# How to apply linear stretch from [-1, 1] to [0, 255]?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, stretch

I have a script which calculates the [Normalized Difference Vegetation Index (NDVI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalized_Difference_Vegetation_Index) from 4-band geotiffs and writes the NDVI as a geotiff.  I am working with aerial imagery as [4-band geotiffs](ftp://ftp.agrc.utah.gov/Imagery/NAIP2011_4-band/) at 1m spatial resolution.  The output NDVI geotiff ranges from -1 to 1 and is 32-bit floating point.  How can I apply a linear stretch so that the output ranges from 0 - 255 in [8-bit unsigned integer format](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/integers.html)?

```
file = 'D:\create_ndvi\3711101_se1.tif';
[I R] = geotiffread(file);
outputdir = 'D:\create_ndvi\'

NIR = im2single(I(:,:,4));
red = im2single(I(:,:,1));

ndvi = (NIR - red) ./ (NIR + red);
double(ndvi);
imshow(ndvi,'DisplayRange',[-1 1]);

tiffdata = geotiffinfo(file);
outfilename = [outputdir 'ndvi_' 'temp' '.tif'];  
geotiffwrite(outfilename, ndvi, R, 'GeoKeyDirectoryTag', tiffdata.GeoTIFFTags.GeoKeyDirectoryTag)
```

Comment: floor of (add one and multiply by 128)

Comment: @vish … and additionally map 1 (-> 256) to 255

Comment: … and cast to `uint8` ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To spell out what's already in the comments:

```
ndvi = floor((ndvi + 1) * 128); % [-1 1] -> [0 256]
ndvi(ndvi < 0) = 0;             % not really necessary, just in case & for symmetry
ndvi(ndvi > 255) = 255;         % in case the original value was exactly 1
ndvi = uint8(ndvi);             % change data type from double to uint8
```